# "What" root or" Which" root?

Tags: word-choice

I read a sentence in "Word Power Made Easy" which was:

> In the etymology section, you will learn what Greek or Latin root give the word its unique meaning and what other words contain the same or related roots.

I don't know why I am having this strong feeling that there should be "which" instead of "what" to precede "Greek or Latin root". Am I right?

Comment: "What" isn't grammatically incorrect, but "give" instead of "gives" is.

Answer (score 1):

Either one is fine in this case. To me, intuitively, "which" sounds better, but both seem grammatically correct. We usually use "which" when there is some specific set of possible options or things it could be. Since there are a very large number of Greek and Latin roots, "what" is also valid.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to the community. Thanks for posting an answer. You would better help the inquirer if you included references though.